# Schengen multiple-entry visa

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry, repeat-visits

I have a one-year multiple-entry Schengen visa issued by Greece in 2023. I used that to visit Greece in 2023.

1. Can I use it to visit Spain in 2024 (within the visa validity period) without visiting Greece in this trip?
2. The visa expires June 14, 2024. I plan to enter Spain on June 1 and depart June 13. Is that likely to be a problem? (I have booked my flight to leave June 13 and can show that).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, after the first visit you can go anywhere in Schengen Area, as long as this is within the 90/180 rule (no more than 90 days in the Schengen Area in any 180-day period), and that you meet the usual conditions (valid passport, return flight, proof of means, no work, etc.).
2. While on the paper this is not a problem, you have very little margin in case of any issues. I would recommend having a few more days between your planned return date and the end of validity of the visa, just in case.

Comment: Thank you jcaron...very helpful